# Navigation through the textfields which are each inside successive tableView cells?

Tags: ios

I am using a tableView Controller and in it I have 4 sections. 1st section contains 2 textfields, 2nd one has 4 textfields, 3rd one has 7 and so on. The problem which I am facing is that I am not able to navigate through the textfields by pressing the next and previous buttons on the keyboard. Actually I have tried a lot of open source libraries to put "Next" and "previous" button on a toolbar above the keyboard but not been able to do so. Every time the keyboard loads there is no toolbar above it.

Maybe It is due to the textfields inside the tableview cell.
Can anybody suggest me the solution to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Previous" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(prev)]
toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(nextTF)],barItem,nil];
[toolbar sizeToFit];
self.yourTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

Next do:

```
-(void)prev
{
    //previous
}

-(void)nextTF
{
    //next
}
```

Comment: thanks for the solution to keep the buttons on the toolbar. But now the problem is that since the textfields are in the table cells. I am not able to access the next textfield from the cell. So, if there is any other way to do it . Can we use the tag property here? or do you have some better approach for the next and previous buttons. please suggest something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! can anybody suggest what to specifically write in the prev and next methods. Do I need to pass the textfield in those methods? Please help